# How to send messages to a topic in Firebase which contains iOS & Android devices

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have read the FCM documentation and found the possibility to add the `condition` parameter for specifying multiple topics.

However it's unclear to me whether or not this is for the same OS topic.

What should be the FCM payload when sending to a topic which contains both iOS & Android devices?
Or sending to FCM a payload with the `condition` specifying both topics (for iOS & Android) but the actual push notification payload data is unclear what should include inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging has no relation between topics and the OS of the devices. Any device can subscribe to any topic, although of course you can choose to have devices subscribe to OS-specific topics.

If you do the latter, you can reach the devices on both/all OS'es by using an OR condition in your message `topic` string:

```
"'TopicA_for_iOS' in topics || 'TopicA_for_Android' in topics"
```

---

If you're wondering how to send one message to both iOS and Android, have a look at the documentation on [customizing messages across platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms).

Comment: Yes, I know this, but sending to Android (or Android package) and sending to iOS (package or single device) are quite different payloads. 
Do firebase has any mechanism to built proper payloads for the corresponding devices in a package (both iOS & Android)

Comment: You mean https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms?

Comment: wow thank you very much... I somehow didn't check this exact page. Seems exactly the documentation I was missing.
Will you please edit your main comment adding this link (for more visibility) so I can mark it as "accepted answer"

Comment: Done.  There's also an `edit` link to doing that yourself btw.